# What is Target in snmp4j lib for SNMP

Tags: windows, networking, snmp, mib, snmp4j

Hello Everyone!!
                    I have a sample code to access some information of device using snmp4j in SNMP protocol...In the sample code they have given to dump the information retrieved into some target address and i am not getting what target address is this ...

Below is my code...

```
 /**
 * This method returns a Target, which contains information about where the
 * data should be fetched and how.
 *
 * @return
 */
private Target getTarget() {
    Address targetAddress = GenericAddress.parse(address);
    CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
    target.setCommunity(new OctetString("public"));
    target.setAddress(targetAddress);
    target.setRetries(2);
    target.setTimeout(1500);
    target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);
    return target;
}
```

}

And this method has been called by **Get**  method of **ResponseEvent** return type...

Answer (score 0):

It's just the IP address of the device from whom you want to retrieve some SNMP information. You can write it like this `"udp:127.0.0.1/161"`

[Here is an example of a simple SNMP Client with snmp4j](http://shivasoft.in/blog/java/snmp/create-snmp-client-in-java-using-snmp4j/)